# How to setup fail2ban with ufw to block IPv6?

Tags: debian, security, fail2ban, ufw

Since `fail2ban Version 0.10` IPv6 is supported. I used `fail2ban` in conjunction with `ufw`. I found that only IPv4 addresses are blocked. This is unfavorable.

```
Failed to execute ban jail 'nginx-noscript' action 'ufw' info 'ActionInfo({'ip': '2400:xx:xx:xx::xx', 'family': 'inet6', 'fid': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7fbe026ee820>, 'raw-ticket': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7fbe026eeee0>})': Error banning '2400:xx:xx:xx::xx'
```

According to the fail2ban changelog it says that not all banactions have been extended to IPv6 yet. Does anyone know a reliable way to get fail2ban to block IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: If you're fine with blocking IPv6 completely, `ip6tables -A INPUT -j DROP` should suffice.

Comment: Then I could also brick up the door because it squeaks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. I'm seeing virtually no malicious traffic on IPv6 that would trigger fail2ban anyway, over a variety of public hosts. All the banactions will eventually get IPv6 support, but if you know any Python you can consider helping by adding the missing support yourself and submitting patches.

That said, the most performant banaction you can use with ufw is `iptables-ipset-*`, and using the IPv6 version of these banactions [will apply to both IPv6 and IPv4](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2475).

```
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6-allports
```

Comment: I have basically the same experience not seeing much malicious activity over ipv6, at least to sshd. Three years on, is this still holding true for everyone?